# Notepad++ roundup second in timestamps

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file with timestamps as follows:

```
00:44:27.25
00:54:15.11
00:45:43.02
00:42:04.87
00:23:03.72
```

I would like to remove the ms and roundup the seconds so it becomes:

```
00:44:28
00:54:16
00:45:44
00:42:05
00:23:04
```

Can this be done using Notepad++?

Comment: You would probably achieve a small parser in python doing just that.
I doubt notepad++ would achieve that

Comment: You probably can but python or javascript would be faster

Comment: You may do this with notepad++ macros, I'll add an answer with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with notepad++ macros and some regexes.

It should work with rough cases where you need to overflow seconds/minutes/hours like in here: `23:59:59.50`

Macros allow you to record some steps. Once recorded, you can `play` them later with a single action. You can even 'save' them to make it persistent across notepad++ restarts. And you can even assign them some keyboard shortcut.

In this case We are going to do six replacements:

**1st replacement**

Search: `[.](?:([0-4])|([5-9]))\d`

Replace: `(?2+)`

**2nd replacement**

Search: `(\d\d):59[+]`

Replace: `\1+:00`

**3rd replacement**

(Repeat second replacement)

**4th replacement**

Search: `^23[+]`

Replace: `00`

**5th replacement**

Search: `9[+]`

Replace: `+9`

**6th replacement**

Search: `(?:(0)|(1)|(2)|(3)|(4)|(5)|(6)|(7)|(8)|(9))[+]`

Replace: `(?{1}1)(?{2}2)(?{3}3)(?{4}4)(?{5}5)(?{6}6)(?{7}7)(?{8}8)(?{9}9)(?{10}10)`

You have a demo of the process here:

[image]